# Gzip not working for some Javascript files

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx, gzip

This a wordpress website using WP Rocket plugin. All JavaScript files are gziped except 4.

I tried many snippets I found on stackoverflow and serverfault but nothing has worked so far.

In response headers it shows server as nginx, but I'm using a .htaccess file. I assume apache is running behind nginx.

Update: I removed the part for gzip but still gzip worked for the files except those 4. I think nginx is overiding settings made in .htaccess.

Comment: Check if they are excluded from wp rocket? Through Plesk or Cpanel > Find Nginx Directives in WEB Config , then you can properly enable gzip and force it to compress whatever you like, check this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder I don't have access to the the apache and nginx configuration file in Plesk.